# linux key combinations [Ctrl + ,] and [Ctrl + .] disabled?

Tags: linux, ssh, keyboard, putty

I am using Putty ssh to a linux server. 
The Key combinations <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> just not work... 
My keyboard is a japanese keyboard
I test with shokey, below is the result of "Pressed [<kbd>,</kbd>][<kbd>.</kbd>][<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>][<kbd>ALT</kbd>+.][<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>][<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>]":

```
$ showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

,        44 0054 0x2c
.        46 0056 0x2e
^[,      27 0033 0x1b
         44 0054 0x2c
^[.      27 0033 0x1b
         46 0056 0x2e
```

it seems like [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>][<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>] just not work...
any ideas??

Comment: Probably Putty is intercepting those key combinations rather than sending them to the SSH server.

Comment: i tried a linux vm on virtualbox, and got exactly same result..., windows is the key???

Comment: I check the global key with ActiveHotKey.exe, and the result is the key combinations is not active...

Answer (score 0):

Caution: You are using an ASCII terminal.

The permitted ctrl-key combinations are defined in the C0 control codes (ASCII value 0 to 31). The key combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> are generally not available here. Also keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> are not supported. The only exception I know is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + a function key (<kbd>F1</kbd>...<kbd>F12</kbd>), where a Control Sequence Introducer (CSI) code is sent.

- [ASCII Control Codes](https://web.archive.org/web/20170427011919/http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm)
- [C0 control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=C0_and_C1_control_codes&oldid=869654887#C0_(ASCII_and_derivatives))
- [Control Sequence Introducer (CSI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ANSI_escape_code&oldid=873901864#CSI_sequences)